# Pipe to shell script issue

Tags: pipe, sh, netcat

I'm having an issue and have had difficulties finding a solution online. My code tails a log file and connects with an external server using netcat when the file is written to.

Here's a quick example of my working code, I'll explain the issue afterwards.

```
# function that watches input for '$servertag' variable
serverwatch() {
  while read data
  do
    if [ `strindex "$data" "$servertag"` -ge 0 ]; then
      ....
      nc <server_ip> 1234
      ....
    fi
  done
}

# Tail the log file and pipe to functions
tail -f messages | serverwatch
```

The issue is that though the connection is successfully established, the data from the 'messages' file is being piped through to netcat. I do some basic parsing on the data locally, but I don't know how to stop the data from being sent through netcat.

I should quickly note that I am looking to have this work on most DD-WRT builds, so I am trying to not install any new packages. Also, bash seems to be broken/minimal on the build I have, so I'm trying to avoid bash.

Please let me know if you have any questions, solutions, or references to other questions that will help with this issue.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netcat inherits the stdin descriptor. Redirect it from somewhere else instead, such as:

```
nc <server_ip> 1234 < /dev/null
```

netcat unfortunately closes the connection when it reaches end-of-input, so if you want the connection to remain open, you could use the `-d` flag.

```
nc -d <server_ip> 1234 < /dev/null
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the help. It looks like the netcat package is missing the 'd' flag on this installation though. It's throwing ' nc: invalid option --d '